# how to solve prisma connection error to mongodb atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, prisma, mongodb-atlas

model.count(\nError in connector: Error creating a database connection. (An error occurred during DNS resolution: proto error: io error: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (os error 10051))"

[here the image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeqVb.png)

this error comes when ever I create connection using prisma "npx prosma generate" and "npm start in my nodejs"

it works fine when ever i change my network, searched a lot some results shows there is firewall problem how can i solve this issue?

network provider asked port number on which prisma is working, how can i find that? also who to get ip address og mongodb altas.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add your error as formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Comment: Do you get this error only on a specific network? Does the error get solved as you switch the network?